# Why firebase rules are denying when tried to push data?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Good day everyone, I'm having a collection like this

```
organization : [
   - id : auto generated
   - users: 
      [0]
      - uid: user1
      - userName: testUser

]
```

I'm working on Angular and tried to push a new user object to the users array but the permission is denied. My account should be marked as passed as I logged in and also has the permission to create, update, delete on this collection.

Here's what I wrote in my Angular app

```
 AddToOrganization(userData, organization){
    firebase.firestore().collection("organizations").doc(organization.id).set(
    {users: [userData]},
    {merge: true}
  );
  }
```

And this is my firebase rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Function
    function getRole(){
        return get(/database/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data;
     }

    function isSignedIn(){
       return request.auth != null;
    }
    function isAdmin(){
    return getRole().roles.keys().hasAny(['admin']) == true;
    }

    // organizations documents
    match /organizations/{organization}{
        allow read;
         allow create,update: if isSignedIn() && request.resoure.data.roles.keys().hasAny(['admin','editor']) == true;
        allow delete: if isSignedIn() && isAdmin() == true;

    }

}
```

I also tried to run on the simulator but it only fire until document level, what I want is to push data to array inside that document.

Comment: Your rules only allow documents in "organizations" to be modified if the document being written has a field called "roles" which is a list that must contain either "admin" or "editor".

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a recursive wildcard syntax `{organization=**}` instead to allow access to an arbitrarily deep hierarchy.

See [this section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) on Recursive wildcards under the Security Rules topic.

Hope that helps!